# How to save extracted information to separate txt files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I have built a code that extracts information from my website's blog (those URLs are in excel file so I pull those from there). I want to have each of the URLs information that I have extracted to be in a separate .txt files (so far I only managed to have those in 1). How can I do that? I have no idea where to even start, I'm very lost here :( Any help would be appreciated.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

i = []

crawl = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/internal_all2.xlsx') 
addresses = crawl['Address'].tolist() 

for row in addresses:
    url = row
    time.sleep(5)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    content = soup.find_all('p')
    
    for content2 in content:
        print(url, content2)
        i.append([url,content2])
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(i)
    df.to_csv('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/scripts/content/test.txt', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append a string to the file name:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

i = []

crawl = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/internal_all2.xlsx') 
addresses = crawl['Address'].tolist() 

for row in addresses:
    url = row
    time.sleep(5)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    content = soup.find_all('p')
    
    for content2 in content:
        print(url, content2)
        i.append([url,content2])
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(i)
    df.to_csv(f'C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/scripts/content/test_{url}.txt', index=False)
```

Comment: I get the following error when using your suggested approach: ValueError: Protocol not known: C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/scripts/content/https

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 3 on Jupyter

Comment: try this instead: ````df.to_csv('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/scripts/content/test_'+url+'.txt', index=False)````

Comment: It was failing due to illegal symbols (:, |) from the URLs that you can't use on .txt file name. Your method works, thanks